# Performance logging/monitoring API/product

Tags: performance, logging, monitoring

I'm not sure how to categorize this question, so let me just explain what I would like and hopefully it will make sense.

I'm after a product (with an API) which I can send different numbers to with tags, and it will take care of all the monitoring/logging stuff.

So for example, say I have a program that downloads a file from a website every 10 seconds.  I would like to monitor how long each of these downloads is taking.  It is quite easy in my application to time how long it takes.  I would now like to send this number and tag (e.g., tag='download time', value = '1.234') to a 3rd party product.  The 3rd party product will now store this value/tag for me.  The product will have a website I can go to, and configure a bunch of things.  So in this example, I could setup an alert like "if 'download time' > 5 send me an email".  I could also visit a website, and view a graph of the logged values and maybe some random statistics (e.g., how often the value has been in the warning/error zone).

I think that's about it.  Sure it wouldn't be *too* hard to do this myself, but I'm no web designer and it'd end up looking pretty ugly.  The more user friendly this kind of product is the more willing users will be to look at the data and actually monitor stuff.

Does such a service exist?

EDIT: Products similar to this: http://dashboard.kpilibrary.com/.  This is pretty much exactly what I was after, but am still searching around.

Comment: Are you looking for a solution on Linux, Windows, Mac, etc?

Comment: Well I guess preferably windows based but it doesnt really matter.  As long as it has an API I can program to that's all that matters.  It could be a web service provided online, or something you install on a local server and run yourself.  Either would be fine.

Comment: have you googled for "Profiler" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many monitoring tools out there. Nagios or RHQ (http://rhq-project.org/) come to mind. Most of the tools work a little different: rather than throwing stuff at them, they have plugins that actively go out and do something to do the measuring. In your example, the plugin would download the file and then report the measurement data to the central server, which can then show you graphs or run alerts on it.

Comment: Cool, these are the kind of products I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, you can use this:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771692%28WS.10%29.aspx
(Windows Performance Monitor)

It pretty much does what you are looking for:

1. Passively collects performance data (E.g. CPU Usage)
2. Can be fed App specific performance metrics (E.g. download time)
3. Can alert you on various thresholds
4. Has a reporting interface for analyzing metrics

EDIT : http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc749249.aspx , more documentation on this.

Comment: Yeah I've looked at this before.  It is *ok* but seems pretty primitive and a fair bit of work to configure/set it up.  Something with a web interface would be great too so it can be viewed from anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

**This answer is specific to Windows.**

If you are looking to analyze events from various systems and you also what the opportunity to create your own events you should consider [ETW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751538.aspx).

The ETW system allows you to consume data events from any number of sub-systems.  You can look at an exhaustive list of built in providers by running the following command:

```
logman query providers
```

The beauty of ETW is that you also have the opportunity to create your own providers and push your own data into the resulting report.  This is a high-performance logging mechanism and is used by Windows itself for many performance investigations.

The resulting report will be an ETL file.  This is a standard file that can be viewed using xPerf, ships with [Windows SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms717422%28v=VS.100%29.aspx), or the build-in ETL analyzer, `tracerpt.exe`.

Comment: Similar to perfmon, this seems a little primitive.  I mean, it's workable, but would require effort to get all the reporting/warnings/alerts going.  I just want to start pushing numbers to an API and then fiddle with settings in the service/program.  Just trying to minimize effort :)

Comment: That is understandable.  ETW is anything but minimal effort :)  Good luck!